# Drupal Views query not executing properly

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-views

I may not be able to explain this properly but please help me with this if you can spot the problem.

I made two versions of the site and both have a view in common. But in the information given below "Live Preview" is that the "Query" is the same but on "Other queries" I see a difference between the two. For the old one:

```
These queries were run during view rendering:
[0.92 ms] execute /* userx : execute */ SELECT ***BIG QUERY HERE*** ASC LIMIT 0, 13
[0.09 ms] drupal_lookup_path
/* userx : drupal_lookup_path */ SELECT src FROM url_alias WHERE dst = 'home' AND language IN('en', '') ORDER BY language DESC
```

And for the new one:

```
These queries were run during view rendering:
[0.15 ms] drupal_lookup_path
/* userx : drupal_lookup_path */ SELECT src FROM url_alias WHERE dst = 'home' AND language IN('en', '') ORDER BY language DESC
[1.95 ms] dblog_watchdog
/* userx : dblog_watchdog */ INSERT INTO watchdog
    (uid, type, message, variables, severity, link, location, referer, hostname, timestamp)
    VALUES
    (73, 'php', '%message in %file on line %line.', 'a:4:{s:6:\"%error\";s:7:\"warning\";s:8:\"%message\";s:96:\"Parameter 2 to draggableviews_view_draggabletable_form() expected to be a reference, value given\";s:5:\"%file\";s:45:\"/home2/boldtige/public_html/includes/form.inc\";s:5:\"%line\";i:372;}', 3, '', ...
```

It seems for the older one [0.92 ms] execute /* userx : execute */ shows the query being executed while on the newer one the query is not being executed. Which explains why I get a blank view on the new one while not on the old one. And it also throws a warning (complaining about the lack of data?).

Is there any solution to this? The views are identical but the new one is not executing the query at all. Any hints will be hugely helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the Drupal cache policy about the views is the same in both sites?

Answer (score 1):

There is an error on the page.

> Parameter 2 to
>   draggableviews_view_draggabletable_form()
>   expected to be a reference, value
>   given

Something is not the same between the two, prehaps the views arguments.

Comment: But I'm sure getting the [0.92 ms] execute /* userx : execute */ part to work will solve the problem. This is simply not happening in the 2nd one. The error is complaining about the lack of data that should be there after this step is executed. Thanks.